# Can't graphic with Chart.js and JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, charts, html5-canvas

I'm having a small problem here, i'm traying to make some charts but i can't make it work and i don't know why. I'm using the Chart.js for the charts graphics.

Here is my HTML5, it has a "canvas" where the chart is going to be with the ID=canvasEjercicio2.

```
<div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
    <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-direction="reverse" data-theme="a" data-transition="slideup"
    href="#principal" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
    Volver
    </a>
    <h3 id="nombreAplicacion">
        Nombre Aplicacion
    </h3>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <h4 id="tituloEstadisticas">
        Estadisticas
    </h4>
    <canvas id="canvasEjercicio2" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery code, something here is not working with the charts, i can't figure it out whats is crashing here:

```
/* ******************************************/
/* *****    PAGE REFRESH ESTADISTICAS   *****/
/* ******************************************/
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#estadisticas', function()
{ 
    graficar();
    mostrarDatosEjercicios();
});

/* ******************************************/
/* ****  MOSTRAR ESTADISTICAS AL ENTRAR  ****/
/* ******************************************/
$('#botonEstadisticas').click(function()
{
    graficar();
    mostrarDatosEjercicios();
}
);

/* ******************************************/
/* ****   MOSTRAR GRAFICOS EJERCICIO 2   ****/
/* ******************************************/
function graficar()
{
    //Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
    var contexto = $("#canvasEjercicio2").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var datos = [
        {
            value: 1,
            color:"#F38630"
        },
        {
            value : 2,
            color : "#E0E4CC"
        },
        {
            value : 3,
            color : "#69D2E7"
        }           
    ];
    var graficoEjercicio2 = new Chart(contexto).Pie(datos);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the very same problem when I found this post although the solution is not very clear. Just for the record I will say the solution was loading the chart in the pageshow event and not before.

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#page-grafica", function(event) {
   // Create the chart here...
}
```